# How to set path in bash_profile on macos catalina 10.15?

Tags: macos

Recently I have installed macos 10.15 (catalina) and I am installing some software which need to set their paths like java_home.

But I am not able to find .bash_profile or .zshrc ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you've never touched these files before then they won't exist on your machine to begin with you'll need to create them in your home directory. Then you'll be able to benefit from their capabilities.

**[Edit]**

To create it open your Terminal and enter the following commands.

`cd ~/`
This will put you in your home directory where these applications look for these files

`touch .bash_profile .zshrc` This will create the two files for you to edit and add your statements into. Since they start with a period they will be hidden so you'll either need to edit them with VIM or something of the sort or show hidden files. Then edit with the text editor of your choosing.

Comment: Thank you, How to create it?

Answer (score 14):

macOS Catalina uses `.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`

`cd && touch .zprofile && open .zprofile`

This command will create and open a .zprofile file, and every path you save in the file will be permanently available on the terminal.

Android SDK paths for examples:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Update for MacOS Monterey: Use `.zshrc` instead of `.zprofile`

Comment: Hello can u show how ur $ANDROID_HOME path looks like?

Comment: @bikashgiri `UserName/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 2):

go easy:

```
nano .zprofile
```

So for example for scala:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/scala/bin
```

Ctl X and save...

Answer (score 0):

The `$PATH` is built by first looking into the content of the file `/etc/paths`, and then looking into every file in the folder `/etc/paths.d`. So, the `$PATH` in the pre-installed `bash` system installation contains every entry in these files, as well as in other shell types.

Additionally, if you want to append the `$PATH` just for `zsh` shells without affecting others (common use case since `zsh` is now the default shell in Mac OS), you can edit `~/.zshrc` the following way:

```
export PATH=/path/available/only/for/zsh/shells:$PATH
```

The above command adds `/path/available/only/for/zsh/shells` to the `$PATH`, and the added path will only be available in `zsh` shells.